# tool for editing live html in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, firebug, ie-developer-tools

Editing live html while developing my site is very easy with Firebug or Chrome developer tools.  But on IE8, the built-in developer tools don't even show you what the live html source is if it was modified with javascript.  You can only view (and sometimes edit) the original source code.

Is there a tool that will allow me to edit the live (possibly modified by javascript) html in IE8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a **Refresh** dom button on dom inspector tab...

[image]

The third button.

Comment: Thank you!  That works!  I would love a much easier tool to edit live html/css though, any good ones exist?

Comment: It's explorer... :-) I am using Aptana studio and I can instantly switch between ie(win only), safari(maconly) and firefox. http://cdn3.afterdawn.fi/screenshots/normal/1336.jpg